# R how to generate size classes from size data

Tags: r

I am attempting to generate a vector of size classes for coral size data I have collected.  What I want to do is create a new column that represents size class for each individual measurement.

I want size classes to be based on every 10 units of measure.  For example, if a coral is size 1-10, I want that to be size class 1, if 11-20 I want that to be size class 2, if 21-30 I want that to be size class 3 etc.

Any help to accomplish this seemingly easy task would be appreciated.  Thanks!

#### Database

```
structure(list(Coral = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Size = c(6, 10, 12, 
40, 14, 22)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    Coral = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"
    )), Size = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

#### Desired Output

```
structure(list(Coral = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Size = c(6, 10, 12, 
40, 14, 22), `Size Class` = c(1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Coral = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Size = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `Size Class` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of your expected output?

Comment: Can you use `cut(x$Size, seq(0,100,by=10), labels=FALSE)` or `1+((x$Size-1) %/% 10)`?

Comment: I have just added a desired output database for reference.  Also, note that I want this to work for corals of any size.  So I do not want it to be limited to 1 through 100 for example.

Comment: r2evans thanks your second solution works!  Just for my reference, can you explain to me what your code means so I can replicate/modify myself?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ceiling` :

```
df$Size_class <- ceiling(df$Size/10)

#  Coral  Size Size_class
#  <dbl> <dbl>      <int>
#1     1     6          1
#2     2    10          1
#3     3    12          2
#4     4    40          4
#5     5    14          2
#6     6    22          3
```

Or `findInterval`

```
df$Size_class <- findInterval(df$Size, seq(0, max(df$Size), 10), left.open = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for these solutions!  ceiling() is a very nice function for this.  Much appreciated Ronak!